# Identify the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3, 2x+4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Consider the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3, 2x+4)$.  Sometimes we can get identifications of rings like these with other more familiar rings if we first kill $x^2-3$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and then kill $2x+4$ or vise versa.  The substitution homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[-2]$ doesn't seem to be relevant since its ideal is $x + 2$ and not $2x+4$.  Working with $x^2 -3$ though I got that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3)\cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ and since the substitution homomorphism is surjective, we have that $\mathbb Z[x](x^2-3, 2x+4) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(2\sqrt{3} + 4)$, making use of the correspondence theorem.  But my use isn't good enough since I thought the identification would be a more familiar ring.

Comment: **Hint** $\,\ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv 3},\,\ 2(2\!+\!x)\equiv 0 \,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv 2(2\!+\!x)(2\!-\!x) \equiv 2(4\!-\!\color{#c00}{x^2}) \equiv 2\ $ therefore $\tag*{}$ $\ (x^2\!-\!3,2x+4) = (x^2\!-\!3,2) = ((x\!+\!1)^2,2)\ \ $

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. You could do this either by

- finding its inverse explicitly, or
- showing that the norm map $N:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by 
  $$N(a+b\sqrt{3})=a^2-3b^2$$
  is multiplicative, and deducing from this that an element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is a unit if and only if its norm is $\pm 1$.

Since $2+\sqrt{3}$ is a unit, the ideal $(2\sqrt{3}+4)$ is the same as the ideal $(2)$. Now observe that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(2)&\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-3,2)\\\\
&\cong \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2-3)\\\\
&=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+1)\\\\
&=\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x+1)^2\\\\
&\cong\mathbb{F}_2[y]/(y^2)
\end{align}$$
where $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the field with two elements.